# Notation of there exists

Tags: notation

I have the following matrix, which represents a state of a state machine:
$$
\mathbf{F} = \begin{pmatrix} 
f_\mathrm{1} & f_\mathrm{2} & f_\mathrm{3} 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
I now want to show in my thesis that the state machine changes state when an element in the matrix becomes one.
Can the following expression be used for this?
$$
\exists \ i \in f_i = 1 \rightarrow \text{Change State to Foo}
$$

Comment: You used the membership symbol $\in$ where it doesn't go. I *have* seen it written backward to mean 'such that' which is what you want, but more standard is to place parentheses around the existential quantifier and the letter it quantifies.

Comment: So it would be:
{∃ i} fi=1→Change State to Foo ?

Comment: I meant round parentheses like (∃ i) fi=1→Change State to Foo. But it would be more clear just to write in words something like: If one of the $f_i$ is $1$ then change state to Foo.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to write something like

$$\bigl[\exists i\in\{1,2,3\} : f_i=1\bigr]\implies\text{State changes to Foo}$$

? I would probably recommend you just write it in words like you just did though; it's more readable.

Comment: So it's like:
"If an f1 or f2 or f3 exists that is 1 -> State changes to Foo"
Right?

Comment: @Peterson you can read it like this: if f_i=1 when i is one of 1,2,3, then the state changes to foo.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much!